# How would I push a view upwards when keyboard is shown when user touches a text view?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have a VC in which I have 3 elements (2 text fields at the top and 1 text view at the bottom). The text view at the bottom is unfortunately hidden when the keyboard appears. I'd like to push my view upwards when the user taps or touches the text view at the bottom, but NOT when they touch the 2 text fields at the top. I've found a solution to push my view upwards but it work when any of the 3 elements are touched, thus hiding the 2 text fields at the top. How can I apply the code below to work only when users touch the text view?

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstTopTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var secondTopTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomTextView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);

}

func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y -= 160
}

func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y += 160
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `UITextField/View` delegate to get notified when a text field begins editing. E.g.

```
- (void)textFielDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Push screen up
}
```

It's worth noting that if the user has a external keyboard attached the on screen keyboard will not show but the screen will still be pushed up. You can avoid this by having a BOOL (or should I say `var` now) that tells you whether the keyboard is showing.

E.g.

```
var isShown = false

func keyboardWillShow(sender:NSNotification) {
    isShown = true
}

func keyboardWillHide(sender:NSNotification) {
    isShown = false
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField:UITextField) {
    if isShown == true {
        // Push screen up.
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution. For some reason it's not working. I'm trying to figure something out.

Comment: Have you connected the delegate outlet of your text field to the view controller?

Comment: Also make sure that `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` is called AFTER `keyboardWillShow:` otherwise `isShown == true` will evaluate to false.

Comment: Yes I've connected the text view to the VC. And I've called the textFieldDidBeginEditing function after the other two. I'm not getting why it's not working.

Comment: Alright I figured out what was the problem. Since I was working with a textView and not a textField I was using the wrong function. I changed it for textViewDidBeginEditing instead of textFieldDidBeginEditing. Sometimes the problems are so simple we try to make them too complicated :p. Thanks for the help. It solved my problem!